# How is $(X,X+Y)$ distributed when $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let $X,Y$ be two independent random variables on the same probability space. The distribution of $X$ is $F^X$ and the distribution of $Y$ is $F^Y$.

The distribution of $X+Y$ is $(F^X * F^Y)$ because of independence. How is the vector $(X,X+Y)$ distributed ?

Comment: You can use the argument of the change of variable to obtain the joint distribution of $(X,X+Y)$.

Comment: I guess the main thing to notice is that $X$ and $X+Y$ are not independent. A complete description of their joint distribution will have to include $Cov(X,X+Y),$ or a way to find it. // Also notice that the support of the joint distribution need not be the Cartesian product of the supports of the two marginal distribution. (See my continued comment in Answer format.)

Answer (score 0):

**Comment** continued. Maybe an example will give you an idea how to proceed. Consider $X\sim\mathsf{Exp}(1)$ and, independently,
$Y\sim\mathsf{Exp}(1).$ Also, let $S = X+Y.$ Tnen
$E(X) = E(Y) = 1, E(S) = 2;$
$Var(X) = Var(Y) = 1;$ $Var(S) = Var(X)+Var(Y)=1+1=2;$
$Cov(X,S) = Cov(X,X+Y) = Var(X) = 0 = 1.$
$\rho_{X,S} = Cor(X,S) = \frac{Cov(X,S)}{SD(X)SD(S)} = \sqrt{2}/2.$

Finally, $S \sim\mathsf{Gamma}(\mathrm{shape}=2,\mathrm{rate}=1),$
perhaps shown by multiplying MGF's.

Simulation, by sampling a million points from $(X,S)$ in R,
sample statistics should match corresponding population parameters to a couple of decimal places.

```
set.seed(2021)
x = rexp(10^6);  y = rexp(10^6)
s = x + y
summary(x); var(x)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
 0.000001  0.287486  0.692905  0.999743  1.384461 13.680783 
[1] 1.001571  # aprx Var(X) = 1
summary(s);  var(s)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
 0.001398  0.961369  1.678681  1.999379  2.692112 18.659487 
[1] 1.996201  # aprx Var(S) = 2
cov(x,s)
[1] 1.000792  # aprx Cov(X,S) = 1
cor(x,s)
[1] 0.7077843 # aprx Cor(X,S) = 0.7072
1/sqrt(2)
[1] 0.7071068
```

Marginal distributions are approximated by histograms and marginal density functions are shown:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 hist(x, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", main="Dist'n of EXP(1)")
  curve(dexp(x), add=T, lwd=2, col="orange")
 hist(s, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", main="Dist'n of GAMMA(2,1)")
  curve(dgamma(x,2,1), add=T, lwd=2, col="orange")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

For the general case, I am not sure how you are expected to show the joint
distribution. For my example, a scatterplot of the first 50,000 points
sampled suggests the joint distribution. Notice that the support of the joint distribution in my example lies entirely in the first quadrant above the 45-degree line. [Perhaps, you're expected to show the jour density as
$f_{(X,S)}(x,s) = f_X(s)f_{Y|X=x}(y|x).]$

```
X = x[1:50000];  S = s[1:50000]
plot(X,S, pch=".", main="Scatterplot of Joint Dist'n")
```

[image]